# Is there a better way of writing this to get friends details

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-fql

When i run this code some times it works and other times it doesnt and gives this exception
Exception: 1: An unknown error occurred

Here is the code

```
$user_access_token= $rowsUser['access_token'];
$user= $rowsUser['userId'];
$email= $rowsUser['email'];

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => APP_ID,
  'secret' => APP_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
));

$access_token=$facebook->setAccessToken($user_access_token);

try{
  $fql = 'SELECT relationship_status,website,contact_email,work,education,
    current_location,uid, name,birthday_date,sex,email, profile_url
    FROM user 
    WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='.$user.')';
  $param  =   array(
    'method'     => 'fql.query',
    'query'     => $fql,
    'callback'    => ''
  );
  $_friends   =   $facebook->api($param);

  print_r($_friends);

}catch(Exception $ex){
  echo $ex;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Its a very common mistake..

```
  $_friends   =   $facebook->api('/'.$param);
```

Use this code and your problem solved. Sometimes Facebook return data without using forward slash but sometimes it throw an Error. its bug in PHP/SDK..

Comment: ok i have changed this but now i am getting this exception OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: Array

Comment: that means your 'param' value is an array